# How to access datastore of different google app engine project?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I want to access datastore of different project. I am using google app engine with PHP for deployment.

Suppose, currently I am deploying to project named "xyz". I want to access Datastore of project named "abc".

Is there any way to access it ?

What I want to do is, I have created a project and using the URL as an endpoint. However, when I deploy the PHP app in the same project, it is replacing the previous content and endpoints are not accessible with the same URL. Is there any way I can deploy endpoints to URL/ and access app engine with actual URL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DataStore REST API directly](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/).

Otherwise, you will need a sort of proxy. One way to do this is to host an app on AppEngine that will expose Datastore entities to you as REST APIs.

Another approach you can use if you do not wish to pay for an AppEngine instance is to use [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/).